# VSCode remote-containers.attachTorunningContainerFromViewlet error

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I'm using Remote-SSH to connect to a remote, and then `Attach Visual Studio Code` on the remote host gives me an error.

```
[2022-01-12 16:59:07.497] [exthost] [error] Shell server terminated (code: 255, signal: null)
    enter code here
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname local-88-centos0-frp: No such host is known. 
     remote-containers.attachToRunningContainerFromViewlet {"value":"ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers","_lower":"ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem on my computer when I tried to connect our lab server:
But others' computers didn't pop up this error when they tried to connect to remote-containers.

```sh
Shell server terminated (code: 255, signal: null)

ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

---

OK finally I find the solution, it maybe a bug on vscode Remote - SSH extension.

1. click extension
2. click Remote-SSH and right click setting
3. find Remote.SSH: Config File (The absolute file path to a custom SSH config file.)

   please leave this setting empty and it is the default at .ssh/config, please modify at there but no input here.

Then I found my problem solved.... Hope it's can help people who met same problem as I did.